# Why are my Illustrator images blurry when placed in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, vector

I am creating simple, clean designs in Illustrator, but when saved as .jpegs or .pngs and placed in an InDesign file at 100% resolution they are blurry as heck.

Comment: (1) Under the View menu, change Screen Mode from Normal to Preview. (2) Also under View, change Display Performance from Typical to High Quality. (3) Try printing it. IND may be conserving display quality for speed, but the end result is actually crisp.

Comment: Why aren't you simply importing .ai files into InDesign?

Answer (score 4):

Converting vector files to bitmaps *always* degrades quality. And since they are not *vector* anymore, your title is wrong.

There is no need to convert AI files to bitmaps to place them into InDesign. Place the native AI files instead.

Comment: Thank you :)   I thought .pngs maintained vector?

Comment: Vectors only exist in PNGs if using Adobe Fireworks... **nowhere** else.

Answer (score 4):

With nothing selected, right-click and go to display performance and make sure 'High Performance' is selected

Comment: This should be the selected answer, though linking the AI file directly is also the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great